# Add a second ILogObserver to a service

Tags: python, twisted

I try to write a small service with twisted.

I created a simple Application, and try to add 2 ILogObservers to my service. But unfortunatly, it doesnt work. The last added Observer is always the observer that will be used.

```
def log(eventDict):
...

def mylog(eventDict):
...

LoopingCall(logSomething).start(1)

application = Application("twistd-logging")
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, log)
application.setComponent(ILogObserver, mylog)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

kay, I found the solution, it was far easier then I suspected.

I just have to add

```
from twisted.python.log import addObserver
```

if I have a secondary log observer

```
def mylogobserver(eventDict):
    # doSth
```

I can add it VERY SIMPLE with

```
addObserver(mylogobserver)
```

Best regards